# Fedora 38 - Added a network card for 10G link to a specific system; former NIC got de-configured and there's no new config file

Tags: fedora, routing, networkmanager

This is on an UPGRADED (not fresh-install - and yes, it matters) Fedora Server 38 box.

After adding a new 10G network card to use as a dedicated link between two systems, the existing, slower-speed NIC's fixed IP address was ignored and another box gave it a DHCP provided address, and there's no configuration file to play with to configure the new card.

`ifconfig` tells me about `enp4s0` and `enp5s0`, these two cards, and I know I'm connected from yet another system to it through the old NIC (`enp5s0`) because the other end of the 10G's `cat7` cable plugged in there goes to the second 10G card, and that system isn't booted. Thus, there's not an IP address for it, either. Plus, I haven't done any configuration on this new NIC yet; I just plugged in the card, booted the box and figured I'd configure, only to have to figure out the new IP because this system requires a fixed IP, and I can't find any entry for the new card anywhere - and the old's ignored. I can't recall having to add a NIC to a system since before NetworkManager existed, so this is a bit new for me.

This older, upgraded system uses the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` strategy (or at least did until now), while a newer, fresh-installation on Fedora Server 38 (both are on this same version) uses `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` version of configuring things.

It might be helpful to understand WHY the system changed behavior just by adding a card, however, it's not clear that it matters and it seems prudent to switch both cards to the newer strategy, just to keep from having surprises in the future.

Of course there's NO configuration file for EITHER NIC in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` (and the one in `sysconfig` isn't being honored any longer). Perhaps I can just use an example from another system using the newer strategy, but I'll be fumbling my way through it without certainty the new file(s) will be read and honored.

Is there a way to get Network Manager to create these configuration files somehow, and THEN I can hack on them?

Once I have both NICs up, I'll need to figure out how to have this new 10G link be the only way these two boxes get to each other unless that link goes down due to some failure.

**New Data**

Oh heck: I went through some notes on NetworkManager and from them tried:

```
nmcli conn show enp4s0
```

but I'm PRETTY SURE it only shows the config file information and NOT anything it's actually honoring live. So, I tried:

```
nmcli connection
```

I got from it some UUID info I can try...

Answer (score 0):

Oh -expletive- I figured it out, at least for the old connection type on the older NIC:

You have to change ALL THREE:

1. the name of the file to the device name, and;
2. the DEVICE= entry and;
3. the NAME= entry.

Bizarre but that's what ya gotta do.

MAYBE the new NIC can be handled similarly, but the DEVICE entry isn't coming up from `nmcli connection`, so I'm not sure.